# React .map creating another container for images

Tags: reactjs, containers

I have a map with display flex with some images and a firebase storage where I can upload a pic, and the pic gets shown in that flex gallery, but there should not be more than 6 in that gallery, and when more than 6 pictures are uploaded, another container should be made where the new pics get placed, the images are held in a state,the code is here

```
//This is the container styles
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10vmin;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skew(5deg);

// This is the map
<div className=" grid grid-rows-3 bg-black">
        <div className={styles.container}>
          {imageList.map((url) => {
            return (
              <div className={styles.card}>
                <img src={url} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>


// This is the
```

I need to make that map somehow know that once a container gets to 6 pictures, it should make another one in the row below,

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Array.prototype.slice() method to separate the image list into two arrays and then render them with two separate maps.

```
const imageListLength = imageList.length;
let imageListTop, imageListBottom;

// Split image list into two arrays
if (imageListLength > 6) {
  imageListTop = imageList.slice(0, 6);
  imageListBottom = imageList.slice(6);
} else {
  imageListTop = imageList;
  imageListBottom = [];
}

return (
  <div className="grid grid-rows-3 bg-black">
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {imageListTop.map((url) => {
        return (
          <div className={styles.card}>
            <img src={url} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
    {imageListBottom.length > 0 && (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {imageListBottom.map((url) => {
          return (
            <div className={styles.card}>
              <img src={url} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

### **EDIT Taking your answer:**

You could expand on your code by adding a loop to the code that renders the images. This loop would check the length of the image list and render the images in groups of 6 until the list is exhausted.

```
const imageListLength = imageList.length;
let imageListTop, imageListBottom;

if (imageListLength > 6) {
  imageListTop = imageList.slice(0, 6);
  imageListBottom = imageList.slice(6);
} else {
  imageListTop = imageList;
  imageListBottom = [];
}

return (
  <div className="grid grid-rows-3 bg-black">
    {/* Loop through the image list */}
    {imageList.map((url, index) => {
      if (index % 6 === 0) {
        return (
          <div className={styles.container}>
            {imageList.slice(index, index + 6).map((url) => {
              return (
                <div className={styles.card}>
                  <img src={url} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hey, this would be very useful but once i upload a lot of images they just stay stacked in the imageListBottom map, it should create another row once that one gets to 6 images as well